# How to get Jest to recognize ES6 absolute path imports prepended with #?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, import, path, jestjs

As per [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_subpath_patterns), they suggest having absolute paths be pre-pended with a #. When running Jest, it doesn't recognize how to find these modules. I get an error `Cannot find module '#loaders/logger' from 'src/loaders/logger.js'` because I import using these absolute paths.

```js
import { logger } from "#loaders/logger";

export const fn1 = () => { 
  // does something 
}
```

I put `src` inside `jest.moduleDirectories` but it's having issue understanding the #. How can I make Jest resolve to the correct path using this notation?

package.json

```json
{
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=14.x.x",
        "npm": ">=6.14.11"
    },
    "type": "module",
    "imports": {
        "#src/*": "./src/*.js",
        "#loaders/*": "./src/loaders/*.js",
    },
    "jest": {
        "moduleDirectories": [
            "node_modules",
            "src"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules npm jest",
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `moduleNameMapper` to my Jest config worked as per [the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string--arraystring)

package.json

```
{
    "jest": {
        "moduleDirectories": [
            "node_modules",
            "src"
        ],
        "moduleNameMapper": {
            "#loaders": "<rootDir>/src/loaders",
            "#(.*)": [
                "<rootDir>/src/embedded/path/$1",
                "<rootDir>/src/$1",
                "<rootDir>/src"
            ]
        }
    },
}
```